# Error code 127 returned when using exec() to run PhantomJS

Tags: php

In my Vagrant environment (haven't tested on the server) I keep getting an error when trying to run PhantomJS using `exec()` from one of my website's controllers.

Here's the code I'm using to debug:

```
exec('/usr/local/node/node-default/bin/node --version', $output, $code);
var_dump($code);
exec('ls -la /usr/local/node/node-default/bin/phantomjs', $output, $code);
var_dump($code);
exec('/usr/local/node/node-default/bin/phantomjs --version', $output, $code);
var_dump($code);
exec('/usr/local/node/node-default/lib/node_modules/phantomjs/bin/phantomjs --version', $output, $code);
var_dump($code, $output);
```

And its output:

```
int 0
int 0
int 127
int 127
array (size=2)
  0 => string 'v0.10.29' (length=8)
  1 => string 'lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 43 Jul 15 18:00 /usr/local/node/node-default/bin/phantomjs -> ../lib/node_modules/phantomjs/bin/phantomjs' (length=128)
```

I can run the command from my terminal and running the above code from PHP's interactive shell (`php -a`) outputs all 0 return codes and the following for the final output:

```
array(4) {
  [0] =>
  string(8) "v0.10.29"
  [1] =>
  string(128) "lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 43 Jul 15 18:00 /usr/local/node/node-default/bin/phantomjs -> ../lib/node_modules/phantomjs/bin/phantomjs"
  [2] =>
  string(5) "1.9.7"
  [3] =>
  string(5) "1.9.7"
}
```

Since the target executable's permissions are 777, what could so be different about these environments that's causing `php -a` to execute PhantomJS just fine whereas my website's controller cannot?

Comment: 1) Try to use `whoami` or `posix_getpwuid(posix_geteuid())['name'];` to see if both of execution (terminal, webserver) run under the same user and usergroup. 2) In some cases terminal and webserver may have different php.ini files, this may restricts your webserver from running some commands (e.g disable_functions, safemode)

Comment: @Athafoud It's running under the `www-data` user but given the file permissions (the actual binary and not the link is rwxr-xr-x) it should be able to access the file. This server is running 5.5, so safemode shouldn't be an issue. I'm not familiar with disable_functions but based off the docs, all of these should be failing if `exec()` was listed, correct?

Comment: Can you print the `$output` for each command ? And also can you check the `disable_functions` (just to be sure) in the php.ini that webserver uses?

Comment: @Athafoud printing $output for each command makes no difference in output since each `exec()` is a single line returned. `disable_functions` does not include `exec`.

Comment: You are right about `$output`. Try using `system()` instead of `exec()`

Comment: @Athafoud same result unfortunately. That whole family of methods doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Ok! Last call, check again the permissions (but 777 should be suficient), thy to use `sudo chown www-data` or `sudo chown root:www-data` on `/usr/local/node/node-default/bin/phantomjs` to be sure that the user www-data can execute the commands you want.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57348/discussion-between-lander-and-athafoud).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if it's simply a permissions error or what, but after further discussion with @Athafoud I've decided to not use npm to install the phantom and instead just download the binary from their site. This works just fine for whatever reason.

Answer (score 2):

I know it's a bit late but I just burned a lot of time investigating this exact issue. For me the problem was that when executed through apache the environment was slightly different so `node` wasn't found. I had to put `/usr/local/bin/node` in the `exec` call and then it worked.